# ¿Como dar de alta a un contacto en una agenda?

Tags: c

Muy buenas.

Tengo que añadir un contacto o bien mediante una agenda desordenada o una agenda ordenada por nombre.

Cuando inserto un contacto en la agenda de forma desordenada me lo inserta bien, el problema viene cuando lo inserto de manera ordenada por nombre, me inserta el contacto pero no de manera ordenada, si no desordenada.

Me gustaría saber cómo hacer para que me inserte el contacto de forma ordenada por nombre.

La función en cuestión es la `número 5` y el `case 5` y no me funciona.

```
// LLibreries.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Constants.
#define NMAX 10

    // Estructura dels jugadors.    
    typedef struct agenda {
        char nom [30];
        char telefon [15];
            int edat;
    } amics;

    // Funcions.
    void introduir_agenda (amics a [], int num);
    void imprimir_agenda (amics a [], int num);
    int buscar_registre (amics a [], int num, int opcio, char cadena_buscar []);
    void ordenar (amics a [], int num, int opcio);
    void insertar_amics (amics a [], int *num, int opcio, amics b);

    // Funció main.
    void main () {
        amics a [NMAX], b;
        int num, n, opcio, res, i;
        char cadena_buscar [30];
            n = 1;      
                while (n!=0) {
                    printf ("\nSelecciona una opcio: \n");
                    printf ("---------------------\n");
                    printf ("   1.- Introduïr agenda. \n");
                    printf ("   2.- Imprimir agenda. \n");
                    printf ("   3.- Buscar un registre per nom o por telèfon. \n");
                    printf ("   4.- Ordenar agenda per nom o edat. \n");
                    printf ("   5.- Donar d'alta un amic nou a l'agenda. \n");
                    printf ("   6.- Donar de baixa un amic de l'agenda. \n");
                    printf ("   0.- Sortir del programa.\n");
                    printf ("------------------------\n");

                    printf ("Opció escollida: ");
                    scanf ("%d", &n);

                    switch (n) {

                        case 1: 
                            system ("clear");

                            printf("Introdueix quants contactes tindrà la teva agenda: ");
                            scanf ("%d", &num);

                            introduir_agenda (a, num);
                            system ("clear");
                            break;

                        case 2: 
                            system ("clear");

                            printf("Aquesta és la teva agenda: \n");
                            imprimir_agenda (a, num);                       
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            system ("clear");

                            printf ("Si vols buscar el contacte mitjançant el telèfon, premi 1.\n");
                            printf ("Si vols buscar el contacte mitjançant el nom, premi 2.\n");
                            printf ("Opció escollida: ");
                            scanf ("%d", &opcio);

                            if (opcio == 1) {
                                printf ("Introdueix el telèfon a buscar: ");
                                scanf ("%s", cadena_buscar);
                                getchar ();
                            }
                            else {
                                printf ("Introdueix el nom a buscar: ");
                                scanf ("%s", cadena_buscar);
                                getchar ();
                            }                           

                            system ("clear");

                            res = buscar_registre (a, num, opcio, cadena_buscar);

                            if (opcio == 1) {
                                if (res != -1) {
                                    printf ("El telèfon cercat correspon al contacte número %d.\n", res + 1);

                                }
                                else {
                                    printf ("El telèfon cercat no correspon a cap contacte.\n");
                                }
                            }

                            else {
                                if (res != -1) {
                                    printf ("El nom cercat correspon al contacte número %d.\n", res + 1);

                                }
                                else {
                                    printf ("El nom cercat no correspon a cap contacte.\n");
                                }
                            }

                            break;

                        case 4:
                            system ("clear");

                            printf ("Si vols ordenar l'agenda per telèfon, premi 1.\n");
                            printf ("Si vols ordenar l'agenda per nom, premi 2.\n");
                            printf ("Opció escollida: ");
                            scanf ("%d", &opcio);

                            system ("clear");

                            ordenar (a, num, opcio);
                            imprimir_agenda (a, num);                       

                            break;

                        case 5:
                            system ("clear");

                            printf ("Si vols introduïr un nou contacte en la agenda desordenada, premi 1.\n");
                            printf ("Si vols introduïr un nou contacte en la agenda ordenada per nom, premi 2.\n");
                            printf ("Opció escollida: ");
                            scanf ("%d", &opcio);

                            printf ("\nIntrodueix el nom del contacte a afegir: ");
                            scanf ("%s", b.nom);

                            printf ("Introdueix el telèfon del contacte a afegir: ");
                            scanf ("%s", b.telefon);

                            printf ("Introdueix l'edat del contacte a afegir: ");
                            scanf ("%d", &b.edat);

                            insertar_amics (a, &num, opcio, b);

                            break;

                        case 10:
                            system ("clear");

                            break;          
                    }
                }
    }

    // Funció 1.
    void introduir_agenda (amics a [], int num) {
        int i;
            for (i = 0; i < num; i ++) {
                printf ("\nIntrodueix el nom del contacte número %d: ", i + 1);
                scanf ("%s", a[i].nom);

                printf ("Introdueix el telèfon del contacte número %d: ", i + 1);
                scanf ("%s", a[i].telefon);

                printf ("Introdueix l'edat del contacte número %d: ", i + 1);
                scanf ("%d", &a[i].edat);

                //printf ("\n");
            }
    }

    // Funció 2.
    void imprimir_agenda (amics a [], int num) {
        int i;
            for (i = 0; i < num; i ++) {
                printf ("\nContacte %d:\n   - Nom: %s.\n   - Telèfon: %s.\n   - Edat: %d.\n", i + 1, a[i].nom, a[i].telefon, a[i].edat);
            }
    }

    // Funció 3.
    int buscar_registre (amics a [], int num, int opcio, char cadena_buscar []) {
        int i;
            if (opcio == 1) {
                i = 0;
                    while (i < num) {
                        if (strcmp(cadena_buscar, a[i].telefon) == 0) {
                            return (i);                         
                        }
                        i ++;                       
                    }
            }

            else {
                i = 0;
                    while (i < num) {
                        if (strcmp (cadena_buscar, a[i].nom) == 0) {
                            return (i);
                        }
                        i ++;
                    }
            }
            return (-1);
    }

    // Funció 4.
    void ordenar (amics a [], int num, int opcio) {
        int i, j, canvi;
            amics aux;
            if (opcio == 1) {
                canvi = 1;
                i = 0;
                    while (canvi == 1) {
                        canvi = 0;
                            for (j = 0; j < (num - i - 1);j ++) {
                                if (strcmp (a[j].telefon, a[j + 1].telefon) > 0) {
                                      aux = a[j];
                                      a[j] = a[j + 1];
                                      a[j + 1] = aux;
                                      canvi = 1;
                                }
                            }
                        i ++;
                    }
            }

            else {
                canvi = 1;
                i = 0;
                    while (canvi == 1) {
                        canvi = 0;
                            for (j = 0; j < (num - i - 1);j ++) {
                                if (strcmp (a[j].nom, a[j + 1].nom) > 0) {
                                      aux = a[j];
                                      a[j] = a[j + 1];
                                      a[j + 1] = aux;
                                      canvi = 1;
                                }
                            }
                        i ++;
                    }

            }
    }

    // Funció 5.
    void insertar_amics (amics a [], int *num, int opcio, amics b) {
        int i, pos_max;
            if (opcio == 1) {
                a [*num] = b;
                *num = *num + 1;
            }

            else {
                i = 0;
                    while ((strcmp (a[i].nom, b.nom) < 0) && (i < *num)){
                        i ++;
                        pos_max = i;
                        }

                    for (i = *num; i > pos_max; i--){
                        a [i] = a [i-1];
                        }

                    a [pos_max] = b;

                    *num = *num + 1;    
            }
    }
```

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Ya lo he solucionado, dejo el código aquí.:

```
// LLibreries.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Constants.
#define NMAX 10

    // Estructura dels jugadors.    
    typedef struct agenda {
        char nom [30];
        char telefon [15];
            int edat;
    } amics;

    // Funcions.
    void introduir_agenda (amics a [], int num);
    void imprimir_agenda (amics a [], int num);
    int buscar_registre (amics a [], int num, int opcio, char cadena_buscar []);
    void ordenar (amics a [], int num, int opcio);
    void insertar_amics (amics a [], int *num, int opcio, amics b);

    // Funció main.
    void main () {
        amics a [NMAX], b;
        int num, n, opcio, res, i;
        char cadena_buscar [30];
            n = 1;      
                while (n!=0) {
                    printf ("\nSelecciona una opcio: \n");
                    printf ("---------------------\n");
                    printf ("   1.- Introduïr agenda. \n");
                    printf ("   2.- Imprimir agenda. \n");
                    printf ("   3.- Buscar un registre per nom o por telèfon. \n");
                    printf ("   4.- Ordenar agenda per nom o edat. \n");
                    printf ("   5.- Donar d'alta un amic nou a l'agenda. \n");
                    printf ("   6.- Donar de baixa un amic de l'agenda. \n");
                    printf ("   0.- Sortir del programa.\n");
                    printf ("------------------------\n");

                    printf ("Opció escollida: ");
                    scanf ("%d", &n);

                    switch (n) {

                        case 1: 
                            system ("clear");

                            printf("Introdueix quants contactes tindrà la teva agenda: ");
                            scanf ("%d", &num);

                            introduir_agenda (a, num);
                            system ("clear");
                            break;

                        case 2: 
                            system ("clear");

                            printf("Aquesta és la teva agenda: \n");
                            imprimir_agenda (a, num);                       
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            system ("clear");

                            printf ("Si vols buscar el contacte mitjançant el telèfon, premi 1.\n");
                            printf ("Si vols buscar el contacte mitjançant el nom, premi 2.\n");
                            printf ("Opció escollida: ");
                            scanf ("%d", &opcio);

                            if (opcio == 1) {
                                printf ("Introdueix el telèfon a buscar: ");
                                scanf ("%s", cadena_buscar);
                                getchar ();
                            }
                            else {
                                printf ("Introdueix el nom a buscar: ");
                                scanf ("%s", cadena_buscar);
                                getchar ();
                            }                           

                            system ("clear");

                            res = buscar_registre (a, num, opcio, cadena_buscar);

                            if (opcio == 1) {
                                if (res != -1) {
                                    printf ("El telèfon cercat correspon al contacte número %d.\n", res + 1);

                                }
                                else {
                                    printf ("El telèfon cercat no correspon a cap contacte.\n");
                                }
                            }

                            else {
                                if (res != -1) {
                                    printf ("El nom cercat correspon al contacte número %d.\n", res + 1);

                                }
                                else {
                                    printf ("El nom cercat no correspon a cap contacte.\n");
                                }
                            }

                            break;

                        case 4:
                            system ("clear");

                            printf ("Si vols ordenar l'agenda per telèfon, premi 1.\n");
                            printf ("Si vols ordenar l'agenda per nom, premi 2.\n");
                            printf ("Opció escollida: ");
                            scanf ("%d", &opcio);

                            system ("clear");

                            ordenar (a, num, opcio);
                            imprimir_agenda (a, num);                       

                            break;

                        case 5:
                            system ("clear");

                            printf ("Si vols introduïr un nou contacte en la agenda desordenada, premi 1.\n");
                            printf ("Si vols introduïr un nou contacte en la agenda ordenada per nom, premi 2.\n");
                            printf ("Opció escollida: ");
                            scanf ("%d", &opcio);

                            printf ("\nIntrodueix el nom del contacte a afegir: ");
                            scanf ("%s", b.nom);

                            printf ("Introdueix el telèfon del contacte a afegir: ");
                            scanf ("%s", b.telefon);

                            printf ("Introdueix l'edat del contacte a afegir: ");
                            scanf ("%d", &b.edat);

                            if (opcio == 2) {
                                ordenar (a, num, opcio);
                            }

                            insertar_amics (a, &num, opcio, b);

                            break;

                        case 10:
                            system ("clear");

                            break;          
                    }
                }
    }

    // Funció 1.
    void introduir_agenda (amics a [], int num) {
        int i;
            for (i = 0; i < num; i ++) {
                printf ("\nIntrodueix el nom del contacte número %d: ", i + 1);
                scanf ("%s", a[i].nom);

                printf ("Introdueix el telèfon del contacte número %d: ", i + 1);
                scanf ("%s", a[i].telefon);

                printf ("Introdueix l'edat del contacte número %d: ", i + 1);
                scanf ("%d", &a[i].edat);

                //printf ("\n");
            }
    }

    // Funció 2.
    void imprimir_agenda (amics a [], int num) {
        int i;
            for (i = 0; i < num; i ++) {
                printf ("\nContacte %d:\n   - Nom: %s.\n   - Telèfon: %s.\n   - Edat: %d.\n", i + 1, a[i].nom, a[i].telefon, a[i].edat);
            }
    }

    // Funció 3.
    int buscar_registre (amics a [], int num, int opcio, char cadena_buscar []) {
        int i;
            if (opcio == 1) {
                i = 0;
                    while (i < num) {
                        if (strcmp(cadena_buscar, a[i].telefon) == 0) {
                            return (i);                         
                        }
                        i ++;                       
                    }
            }

            else {
                i = 0;
                    while (i < num) {
                        if (strcmp (cadena_buscar, a[i].nom) == 0) {
                            return (i);
                        }
                        i ++;
                    }
            }
            return (-1);
    }

    // Funció 4.
    void ordenar (amics a [], int num, int opcio) {
        int i, j, canvi;
            amics aux;
            if (opcio == 1) {
                canvi = 1;
                i = 0;
                    while (canvi == 1) {
                        canvi = 0;
                            for (j = 0; j < (num - i - 1);j ++) {
                                if (strcmp (a[j].telefon, a[j + 1].telefon) > 0) {
                                      aux = a[j];
                                      a[j] = a[j + 1];
                                      a[j + 1] = aux;
                                      canvi = 1;
                                }
                            }
                        i ++;
                    }
            }

            else {
                canvi = 1;
                i = 0;
                    while (canvi == 1) {
                        canvi = 0;
                            for (j = 0; j < (num - i - 1);j ++) {
                                if (strcmp (a[j].nom, a[j + 1].nom) > 0) {
                                      aux = a[j];
                                      a[j] = a[j + 1];
                                      a[j + 1] = aux;
                                      canvi = 1;
                                }
                            }
                        i ++;
                    }

            }
    }

    // Funció 5.
    void insertar_amics (amics a [], int *num, int opcio, amics b) {
        int i, pos_max;
            if (opcio == 1) {
                a [*num] = b;
                *num = *num + 1;
            }

            else {
                i = 0;
                    while ((strcmp (a[i].nom, b.nom) < 0) && (i < *num)){
                        i ++;
                        }

                    pos_max = i;


                    for (i = *num; i > pos_max; i--){
                        a [i] = a [i-1];
                        }

                    a [pos_max] = b;

                    *num = *num + 1;

            }
    }
```

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado. Dejo la edición con el algoritmo resuelto.

Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, pon la respuesta como respuesta, no como adición a la pregunta. Luego la puedes marcar como aceptada. Eso incluso te puede dar una nueva medalla!

Comment: Saludos Alex, ten en cuenta para tu próxima pregunta, es mejor agregar un [mcve] y no todo el código de tu programa, así nos es más facil saber cuál es tu problema y cómo ayudarte a resolverlo.

Comment: @AlexIglesias asi como esta, esta pregunta no se entiende, y la respuesta menos. Las respuestas deben ir como respuestas, y explicadas. si no, habria que borrar la pregunta ya que como esta, no le sirve a nadie mas.

Comment: @Alfabravo No sé como poner marcar mi respuesta como respuesta, ya que he puesto la respuesta en mi pregunta jeje. Lo siento, soy nuevo en StackOverFlow.

Comment: @NaCl Vale, gracias, lo tendré en cuenta la próxima vez. Saludos.

Comment: @gbianchi Yo creo que se entiende perfectamente, no explico mi error porqué no hay nada que explicar, si comparas el código te darás cuenta del error.

Comment: No @AlexIglesias, el sitio no funciona asi. Las respuestas no van en las preguntas, van en las respuestas. y las respuestas son ademas del codigo, la explicacion de porque es la solucion. Asi como esta, nadie puede encontrar la respuesta rapidamente. y si solo fue que faltaba escribir el codigo, entonces no es una respuesta porque no habia un problema a solucionar.

Comment: Alex, si ves en la página principal, verás que se muestra cuándo una pregunta tiene respuestas y cuándo tiene una respuesta aceptada (equivalente al SOLVED de otros foros). Que no añadas tu propia respuesta como respuesta aceptada (en el recuadro debajo) y la aceptes le indica a otros que tu pregunta no se respondió. Lo que varios han sugerido busca simplemente que otros en el futuro sepan que tu problema pudo resolverse y usen tu solución. Ya que estamos, también pueden votar tu respuesta y subir tu reputación.

Comment: @Alfabravo Vale, ¿puedes decirme como marco mi pregunta como solucionada?
Un saludo.

Comment: Debajo de todos estos comentarios hay un recuadro "Tu Respuesta". Ahí pones lo que encontraste como solución a tu propio problema y le das clic al botón "Publica tu respuesta" que está debajo. Una vez esté publicada, debe salir un *tick* (✔) a la izquierda de la respuesta; puedes darle clic para marcar la respuesta como aceptada.